# Continue a CSS animation after element is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am making this game, and there is a button with a cooldown animation. The player clicks this button, and when the animation finishes, they get something (sort of like a clicker game).

There is a nav bar. I want the player to be able to click this button, go to another tab (and therefore hide this button), and come back to see the animation finished.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```js
    $(".cooldown-button").click(function(){
        $(".cooldown-inner").css("animation","none");
        $(".cooldown-inner").hide().show();
        $(".cooldown-inner").css("animation","cooldown 2000ms linear");
    });
    $(".hide").click(function(){
        $(".cooldown-button").hide();
    });
    $(".show").click(function(){
        $(".cooldown-button").show();
    });
```

```css
        .cooldown-button
        {
            position: relative;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0.2vh 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 20vw;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
            .cooldown-inner
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: #BBB;
                width: 0;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: -1;
            }
            @keyframes cooldown
            {
                0% {width: 100%}
                100% {width: 0%}
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cooldown-button">Do something<div class="cooldown-inner"></div></div>

    <div class="hide">Hide</div>
    <div class="show">Show</div>
```

Essentially, I want to be able to click the cooldown button, click hide, wait a few seconds, click show, and see the animation finished (or almost done). CUrrently, it just restarts.

Comment: If you wish this cooldown UI to be linked with your game logic, e.g to not allow a set of actions while cooling down, etc., then do not control its status via CSS animations. A time will come you will need to have a way to get and set precise values, and CSS animations are not the right tool. Instead set up a js animations and control it all entirely.

Comment: I have a cooldown counter, but using a css animation is simpler

Comment: So simple that you already are on stackoverflow to do something as simple as keeping it running :-) It may look simpler now, but from experience, controlling a css animation is far from being simple. You'd better learn right now how to do a simple js powered animation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done with a CSS trick. If you give the HTML a wrapper and then use a pseudo-element with a white background, `position: absolute`, and a `z-index: -2`, you can use `addClass` and `removeClass` in your jQuery to hide the "Do Something" button behind this pseudo-element. I made a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/jaredgorski/pen/pGybLQ), as well as a snippet below.

See it in action:

```js
$(".cooldown-button").click(function(){
    $(".cooldown-inner").css("animation","none");
    $(".cooldown-inner").hide().show();
    $(".cooldown-inner").css("animation","cooldown 2000ms linear");
});
$(".hide").click(function(){
    $(".cooldown-button").addClass("hidden");
});
$(".show").click(function(){
    $(".cooldown-button").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.wrapper:after {
  background: white;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.cooldown-button {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2vh 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cooldown-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #BBB;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -3;
}

@keyframes cooldown {
  0% {
    width: 100%
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cooldown-button">
    Do something
    <div class="cooldown-inner"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="hide">Hide</div>
  <div class="show">Show</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".cooldown-button").click(function() {
  $(".cooldown-inner")
    .css("animation", "cooldown 4s linear")
    .one("animationend", function() {
      $(this).css("animation", "none")
    });
});
$(".hide").click(function() {
  $(".cooldown-button").addClass('hide');
});
$(".show").click(function() {
  $(".cooldown-button").removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.cooldown-button {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2vh 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cooldown-button.hide {opacity:0}

.cooldown-inner {
  transition:.5s;
  opacity:1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #BBB;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes cooldown {
  0% {
    width: 100%
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cooldown-button">Do something
  <div class="cooldown-inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="hide">Hide</div>
<div class="show">Show</div>
```

for hiding and showing element instead of using jQuery `hide()` change `opacity` of an element from 1 to 0, to show it again change it from 0 to 1 and you can see animation continuous

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```js
$(".cooldown-button").click(function() {
  $(".cooldown-inner")
    .css("animation", "cooldown 4s linear")
    .one("animationend", function() {
      $(this).css("animation", "none")
    });
});
$(".hide").click(function() {
  $(".cooldown-button").addClass('hidden');
});
$(".show").click(function() {
  $(".cooldown-button").removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.cooldown-button {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2vh 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {position:absolute; transform:scaleX(0)}

.cooldown-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #BBB;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes cooldown {
  0% {
    width: 100%
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cooldown-button">Do something
  <div class="cooldown-inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="hide">Hide</div>
<div class="show">Show</div>
```